# Connection Problem Simulink (matlab 2017a - ROS Network in Virtual Machine(Ubuntu 14.14)

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please I am connecting Simulink(matlab 2017a) to the ROS Network deployed in a Virtual Machine- Ubunt 14.04  in my PC, I can see all the nodes, topics, etc. However from Simulink I can not subscribe to the topics sent by the virtual machine. I can subscribe and view the topics sent  by Simulink  from the virtual machine. Thank you so much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304028/connection-problem-simulink-(matlab-2017a---ros-network-in-virtual-machine(ubuntu-14.14)/) by [roberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37671/roberto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're using a VM, you'll have to review the networking configuration it uses.

If it's using NAT, connecting to processes running *inside* the VM will not be possible without (extensive) port forwarding. With an application that uses dynamically chosen ports (ie: random), then forwarding will be difficult to setup correctly. All your ROS nodes use random ports (well, from a certain range, but still random enough).

If you're running this on a machine in an unmanaged network (ie: at home, or in a really small company with no IT policy/department), you may get away with using *bridged networking* between the host and the VM. Your VM will get a "real" IP address, allowing it to communicate with *all* other hosts on your network, as-if it was a real computer.

If you're in a company (that has strict networking policies) or don't want to give your VM an IP from your physical network, then try to use *host only* networking. It is like bridging, but only within your own computer.

---

Note that after you have all of this setup, you need to make sure ROS (and Ubuntu) in the VM are properly configured for a multi-machine setup. See [wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) for a start with that, or one of the myriad of questions here on ROS Answers about setting up Matlab for use with ROS (use Google: `matlab ros_ip ros_hostname site:answers.ros.org`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roberto](https://answers.ros.org/users/37671/roberto/) on 2018-09-25**:
Thanks a lot for your replying, it was so useful. Now, based on your suggestions, it is working well under the host only networking. I was using bridge networking in an unmanaged network and also trying with NAT, Thanks,